# mysql select distinct column A with the min value of column B and relevant column C

Tags: mysql

I have 3 columns A & B. column A may has rows with same ids but the ids have different values. how to select distinct column A with the min value of column B , all with pure MySQL and with no php? th

I am sorry because I changed the question, but this is to clear myself. say this is the table:

```
ColumnA ColumnB ColumnC  

a       1       car    
a       5       mouse    
b       6       key  
b       2       press  
b       4       enter  
c       77      board  
c       22      check
```

the result I expect is:

```
ColumnA ColumnB ColumnC

a       1       car
b       2       press
c       22      check
```

Comment: You can look at this fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c1a71/6

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC
FROM table
WHERE ColumnB = (SELECT MIN(ColumnB) 
       FROM table AS t 
       WHERE t.ColumnA = table.ColumnA)
```